# In python 2.7 raw_input is not working as expected

Tags: python

The raw_input is not working as expected in the below python script,

```
var = raw_input("Enter a value")
print"The value is", var
```

RESULT:

```
Enter a valueThe value is 1
```

Firstly it does not print 'Enter the value' and waits till we print the value.
On entering the value, the above result is displayed.

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong?

Comment: How are you calling it? How did you install Python? If you are using it in a pipe, that is what you get. `echo 1| python test.py`

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to refer what you are doing!!

As raw_input() is used to take the user input from keyboard under Python programming language

And if you are passing argument in that, it is going as "prompt", which is going to be there if you have defined!!

Example: if you do this..

```
var = raw_input("\>")
print"The value is ", var
```

Output will be

```
\>The value is 1
```

only the prompt is changing..

For more details please refer documentation [Python #raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)